# &amp;minus; not getting reflected in html

Tags: html

The minus sign is not getting reflected in the html file when I dynamically pass it from the java file as `&amp;minus;`

Same when i pass `&minus;` it gets decoded in HTML file.

Can anyone help how to make the  `&amp;minus` to work?

Comment: Show the code you are using. And make it clear which of `&amp;minus;`, `&minus;`, and `&minus` you are using. Consider writing the actual MINUS SIGN “−” instead of using an entity reference (named character reference).

Comment: Well... yes. `&amp;minus;` is the correctly encoded form of the text "`&minus;`". Are you double-encoding?

Answer (score 0):

try using & for '&' and - for '-' refer [Documentation](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) for ascii HTML codes. This might work.